# Maven: must be a valid version but is 'RELEASE'

Tags: java, maven

I am very new to Maven and trying to use the [CarbonFive DB Migration](http://code.google.com/p/c5-db-migration/) from Maven.

Following their documentation, I added the following in my `pom.xml`

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>c5-public-repository</id>
        <url>http://mvn.carbonfive.com/public</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

and

```
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>com.carbonfive.db-support</groupId>
            <artifactId>db-migration-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bb</url>
                <username>bb</username>
                <password>bb</password>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

Now when I try to run migration

```
$ mvn db-migration:migrate
```

I see error saying

```
[ERROR]     'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.carbonfive.db-support:db-migration-maven-plugin must be a valid version but is 'RELEASE'. @ line 165, column 26
```

and `line 165` is

```
<version>RELEASE</version>
```

which is as per their documentation.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you want to always use the latest version of the plugin, just omit the 'version' tag.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to fill in the release you want.  Looks like, from http://code.google.com/p/c5-db-migration/:

> Latest Version: 0.9.9-m5 (check out the new check goal!)

So try `0.9.9-m5` in place of `RELEASE`.

Maven versions are always in the format `x.y.z-DESCRIPTOR` with `y`, `z` and `DESCRIPTOR` optional.

Comment: I tried that but that doesn't help either. I removed `<version>RELEASE</version>` and it started to work. I do not know if that is correct way to do it

Comment: No, it's not quite correct, there are a two camps among Maven users: those that like to _lock down_ the versions of the plugins they use for _build reproducibility_, and those that like to let Maven _auto-update its plugins_, for instant upgrade of its features. It __should__ work with [`<version>0.9.9-m5</version>`](http://mvn.carbonfive.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/carbonfive/db-support/db-migration-maven-plugin/0.9.9-m5/).

Answer (score 1):

Maven has [version rules](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html). It is possible to change them, but normally there is no need.

If you look at their [Nexus](http://mvn.carbonfive.com/public), you'll see that the latest stable version of `db-migration-maven-plugin` is [0.9.8](http://mvn.carbonfive.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/carbonfive/db-support/db-migration-maven-plugin/0.9.8/).